# Assign random but unique value between two dataframes

Tags: r, join

I have two objects:

*Dataframe 1*:

```
Address City
 xyz    City1
 xyy    City1
 xxx    City2
 ...    ...
```

*Dataframe 2*

```
Column 1 Column 2 City
....     ...      City1
....     ...      City2
```

I want to join the two data-frames, so that I assign a random, but unique address from dataframe one to dataframe two, given that there is a match between the cities.

*Essentially, the idea is to assign a random address for a given city.*

I don't believe a join would work here, as the size of the dataframes varies and I need to assign a unique address value. Perhaps I'm mistaken though.

Any ideas how I can pull this off?

Comment: Am I getting this right: There's one or more random address(es) in dataframe1 which match each city in dataframe2? Edit: Maybe you could provide a testdataset.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data. And the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to pick a random row for each `City` in your first dataset and then join that info back to your second dataset.

```
# example datasets
df1 = read.table(text = "Address City
xyz City1
xyy City1
xxx City2
zzz City2", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text = "Column1 Column2 City
1     3      City1
2     4      City2", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)  # for reproducible results

df1 %>%
  group_by(City) %>%              # for each city 
  sample_n(1) %>%                 # pick a random row
  right_join(df2, by="City") %>%  # right join df2
  ungroup()                       # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Address City  Column1 Column2
#   <chr>   <chr>   <int>   <int>
# 1 xyz     City1       1       3
# 2 xxx     City2       2       4
```

Comment: Yes - that's the gist. But, I also need to make sure no address appears twice. So, I sample one address from DF1 (sample_n), but than how do I make sure I do not assign it twice later on?

Comment: You sample one (random) address per city. An address might appear twice only if it exists for another city as well. Is that possible?

Comment: No. That would not be possible.

Comment: But is not a possible scenario that with sample_n, I would resample the same address after n rounds/picks? I haven't looked into how the function is built.

Comment: That's why we add `group_by(City)` before sampling. In order to sample 1 row for a specific city and then move to the next city to sample, etc. Also, without the grouping, `sample_n(1)` will sample 1 row from the whole dataset! Grouping is what forces sampling to get 1 row for each city.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` alternative:

Scramble the *entire* address data *once* (`sample(.I)`), join on 'City', and select the first of the matches (`mult = "first"`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)
d1[d1[ , sample(.I)]][d2, on = "City", mult = "first"]

#    City Address
# 1:   c1      a2
# 2:   c2      a3
# 3:   c3      a1
# 4:   c4      a2
```

---

```
d1 <- data.frame(City = rep(paste0("c", 1:4), each = 4),
                 Address = paste0("a", 1:4))
d2 <- data.frame(City = paste0("c", 1:4))
```

---

Don't know if speeed is an issue, but this should be faster on a larger data.